# Can I use Google API or Google Maps in web application developed with ArcGIS APIs?

Tags: open-source-gis, google-maps-api, arcgis-api-wpf

I need to know that is it possible to use Google Maps (as a base map) and its GIS functionalities (like find/search features) in my web application developed with ArcGIS API for Silverlight/JavaScript.

Also I don't want to use ArcGIS server. I want to use open source GIS technology.

Answer (score 1):

See:
[Looking for Alternatives to Google gmaps utility widget for ArcGIS JSAPI API](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59120/looking-for-alternatives-to-google-gmaps-utility-widget-for-arcgis-jsapi-api)
In the [Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) is specified that you must not access map tiles or imagery through interfaces or channels (including undocumented Google interfaces) other than the Maps API(s).